# Can nodejs handle very large objects (given enough memory)

Tags: node.js

As a side project, I am analyzing handpicked players for fantasy football. I am building arrays of player ids in an object format `{[teamIdentifer:string]:playerIds[]}`.

Obviously the number of combinations can get quite large - but I seem to be getting a very odd holdup around 9 million teams.

Every million rows, I print a status update:

[image]

As you can see, each million teams takes 6-12 seconds to form. Until I try to get to 9mil, then the script SLOWLY stalls and eats up memory until it reaches its limit of 12 GB. This takes about 20 minutes.

So we go from 6GB of memory, and 10ish seconds per million rows, to crashing after 20+ minutes.

What gives? Does node have some hard-coded limit for an object being too large?

I am willing to add a lot of memory via swap and even let this run for days if necessary, but I don't think it will help. Are there any benchmarking tools to find out what the problem is?

Comment: Save your data into a database so memory is not holding all of your data.

Comment: I agree with the above comment.  This sounds like an exercise for a database and selectively querying and loading data, not keeping this much data all in memory.  Or perhaps loading only parts of the data set at a time, analyzing that, then load a different set of data, analyze it, etc...  There are no fixed object size limits in node.js, just memory usage limits based on your environment and practical limitations based on performance.